# How to further implement it to make it workable in php?

Tags: php, foreach, iterator

I am beginner in php

As i know **Iterator** is an interface to create iterator of a class and has 5 abstract methods. But i dont know when these methods are called when these methods perform their duty in foreach loop, what these methods do ?

All internet is inspected fot those 5 methods including php.net, sitepoint, etc.

Can anyone tell what does these methods do in **Iterator** interface in foreach loop?

Please explain it with the following piece of code as example.

```
class myClass implements Iterator{

    public function rewind(){
        //--What it will do ?
    }

    public function current(){
        //--What it will do ?
    }

    public function key(){
        //--What it will do ?
    }

    public function next(){
        //--What it will do ?
    }

    public function valid(){
        //--What it will do ?
    }

}

$obj = new myClass();

foreach($obj as $value){

    //--What is the duty or realtionship of rewind(), current(), key(), next(), valid() methods here in foreach loop ?

}
```

Can anyone tell in simple and easy words ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php#iterator.examples

Comment: I am already on that page which does not provide information that is able to understand i am beginner.

Comment: The top comment on the page linked to by @u_mulder is actually an exact answer to your question: http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php#96691 -- that explains what each function does and in what order they are called during a `foreach`

Comment: So how they are called in foreach what does it mean that they are called in foreach, what exactly it means ?

Comment: It means `foreach($obj as $key => $value)` does exactly the same as the example while-loop in that comment (just replace `$it` with `$obj` in their code)